# Performing $lookup based on matching object attribute in other collection's array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to perform `$lookup` on collection with conditions, the problem I am facing is that I would like to match the `text` field of all objects which are inside an array (`accounts` array) in other (`plates`) collection. 
I have tried using `$map` as well as `$in` and `$setIntersection` but nothing seems to work. And, I am unable to find a way to match the text fields of each of the objects in array.

My document structures are as follows:

`plates` collection:

```
{
    "_id": "Batch 1",
    "rego" : "1QX-WA-123",
    "date" : 1516374000000.0
    "accounts": [{
        "text": "Acc1",
        "date": 1516374000000
    },{
        "text": "Acc2",
        "date": 1516474000000
    }]
}
```

`accounts` collection:

```
{
    "_id": "Acc1",
    "date": 1516374000000
    "createdAt" : 1513810712802.0
}
```

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
{
    $lookup: { 
        from: 'plates',
        let: { 'accountId': '$_id' },
        pipeline: [{
            '$match': {
                '$expr': { '$and': [ 
                    { '$eq': [ '$account.text', '$$accountId' ] }, 
                    { '$gte': [ '$date', ISODate ("2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z").getTime() ] },
                    { '$lte': [ '$date', ISODate ("2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z").getTime() ] }
                ]}
            }
        }],
        as: 'cusips' 
    }
},
```

The output I am trying to get is:

```
{
    "_id": "Acc1",
    "date": 1516374000000
    "createdAt" : 1513810712802.0,
    "plates": [{
        "_id": "Batch 1",
        "rego": "1QX-WA-123"
     }]
}
```

Comment: Just curious, but you probably also really want to initiate this "join" from the other direction `plates -> accounts`. The reason being that the "account" detail is inside an "array" within the `plates` collection. So doing it in this direction means you still get "accounts" that are not a match for the account you are joining to from the document. Without some more juggling. Depending on your desired results, you probably want this the other way around to make the selection more simple. And "optimal"

Comment: Why are you modifying your question? The field path within the "data you provided is `"$account.text"` and not `"$account.name"`. And you've been told several times you have them the wrong way around anyway.

Comment: @NeilLunn well I update the question to correct the mistake, anyway, I tried your suggestion and seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would be initiating the aggregation from the `"plates"` collection instead where the initial [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) conditions can filter the date range more cleanly. Getting your desired output is then a simple matter of "unwinding" the resulting `"accounts"` matches and *"inverting"* the content.

Easy enough with MongoDB 3.6 features which you must have in order to use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) with [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/). We even don't need that form for [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) here:

```
db.plates.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "date": { 
      "$gte": new Date("2016-01-01").getTime(),
      "$lte": new Date("2019-01-01").getTime()
    }
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "accounts",
    "localField": "accounts.text",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "accounts"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$accounts" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$accounts",
    "plates": { "$push": { "_id": "$_id", "rego": "$rego" } }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$mergeObjects": ["$_id", { "plates": "$plates" }]
    }
  }}
])
```

This of course is an "INNER JOIN" which would only return `"accounts"` entries where the matc

Doing the "join" from the `"accounts"` collection means you need additional handling to remove the non-matching entries from the `"accounts"` array within the `"plates"` collection:

```
db.accounts.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "plates",
    "let": { "account": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "date": { 
          "$gte": new Date("2016-01-01").getTime(),
          "$lte": new Date("2019-01-01").getTime()
        },
        "$expr": { "$in": [ "$$account", "$accounts.text" ] }
      }},
      { "$project": { "_id": 1, "rego": 1 } }
    ],
    "as": "plates"
  }}
])
```

Note that the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) on the `"date"` properties should be expressed as a regular query condition instead of within the `$expr` block for optimal performance of the query.

The [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) is used to compare the "array" of `"$accounts.text"` values to the local variable defined for the `"_id"` value of the `"accounts"` document being joined to. So the first argument to [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) is the "single" value and the second is the "array" of just the `"text"` values which should be matching.

This is also notably a "LEFT JOIN" which returns all `"accounts"` regardless of whether there are any matching `"plates"` to the conditions, and therefore you can possibly end up with an empty `"plates"` array in the results returned. You can filter those out if you didn't want them, but where that was the case the former query form is really far more efficient than this one since the relation is defined and we only ever deal with `"plates"` which would meet the criteria.

Either method returns the same response from the data provided in the question:

```
{
        "_id" : "Acc1",
        "date" : 1516374000000,
        "createdAt" : 1513810712802,
        "plates" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "Batch 1",
                        "rego" : "1QX-WA-123"
                }
        ]
}
```

Which direction you actually take that from really depends on whether the "LEFT" or "INNER" join form is what you really want and also where the most efficient query conditions can be made for the items you actually want to select.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure how you tried [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/), but it works for me:

```
{
    $lookup: { 
        from: 'plates',
        let: { 'accountId': '$_id' },
        pipeline: [{
            '$match': {
                '$expr':  { '$and': [ 
                    { '$in': [ '$$accountId',  '$accounts.text'] },
                    { '$gte': [ '$date', ISODate ("2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z").getTime() ] },
                    { '$lte': [ '$date', ISODate ("2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z").getTime() ] }
                ]}
            }, 
        }],
        as: 'cusips' 
    } 
}
```

Comment: The `$gte` and `$lte` parts would be a lot more efficient "outside" of the `$expr` where they can actually apply to an index. They are "constant" values and not "field comparisons" afterall.

Comment: Also FYI `{ "$lookup": { "from": "plates", "foriegnField": "accounts.text", "localField": "_id", "as": "cusips" } }, { "$unwind": "$cusips" }, { "$match": { "cusips.date": { "$gte": ISODate ("2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z").getTime(),  "$lte": ISODate ("2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z").getTime() } } }` is basically **exactly** the same as the correction I just mentioned. You need to look at the "explain" output to see why. It's "unwound" but you can always `$group`.

Comment: @Alex Blex $in doesn't work for me. It says the second parameter should be an array but object is supplied

Comment: @Waqas, there are documents in `plates` collection where `accounts` is not an array. Please note it is `bidder.name` in your question, but I assume it supposed to be `accounts.text` since there is no `bidder` in the `plates` document you provided. Apart from that, please follow Neil's answer for better performance. I believe he made the same assumption.

Comment: @AlexBlex yeah i updated the question, however, the `accounts` in `plates' collection is an array of documents

Comment: @Waqas do you confirm `db.plates.find({accounts:{$not:{$type: 'array'}}})` returns 0 documents?